# Composition of the Arabic letters Lam and Alef in Emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, characters, bidirectional-support

When I insert the character `ل` (the Arabic letter Lam) followed by `ا` (the Arabic letter Alef) the result would be `لا`.

In other text editors when I have the word `لا` I can mark (select) each of its characters, for example in the current box that I write this message (in Mozilla Firefox) I can mark (select) `ل` in the word `لا` as shown in the following image

[image]

I can also mark (select ) `ا` in the word `لا` as shown in the below image

[image]

But in Emacs I am not able to mark (select) the letters `ل` and `ا` in the word `لا` individually. In fact for a reason that I do not understand the word `لا` is considered as an entire block (like a character but not exactly) and either both letters are selected or no letter is selected.

I am wondering if this is a bug or an intentional behavior and if there is way which allows to select these letters individually like in many other editors.

Comment: I cannot tell the difference. Firefox, Chrome, and IE on Windows 8 render the two identically.

Comment: It does recognize that there are two characters there -- in the word لان, put  the cursor on the لا and run `M-: (current-column)`, and then put it on the ن and run `M-: (current-column)` again -- they'll be two columns apart rather than 1.

Comment: @PythonNut I apologize if I didn't correctly asked my question. I have revised the question.

Comment: @Dan I have revised the question. I apologize if I didn't correctly stated the problem.

Comment: A composed character in Emacs is just that -- a character -- i.e., the two become one.  A composed character is not rendered as two separate characters close to one another.  Here is an example:  `(defun test-fn () (interactive) (message (compose-string-internal "A|" 0 (length "A|"))))`

Comment: @lawlist when the letter `م` (the Arabic letter M) is composed by `ا` (the Arabic letter A) we obtain `ما`. But I do not have the above problem here. I can select (mark) both `م` and `ا` in Emacs. I think the case of composition of  `Lam+Alef` is weird.

Comment: @lawlist Maybe I would not have correctly used the term `composition`. I mean by `composition` the particular way that the editors *glue* Arabic characters.

Comment: `لا` appears as two (2) characters in `fundamental-mode` using a generic version of Emacs.  Is that the expected behavior in the mode you are using?

Comment: @lawlist you are right about the number of the characters of `لا`. In the Edit I have done about two hours ago, I took back the claim that Emacs consider `لا` as a character. My question is about the inability to select (mark) each characters of `لا` individually. If instead of the Arabic letter `ل` I use another letter I do not have this problem. Try this in any buffer: you can select each letters of the words `با پا تا ثا جا چا حا خا دا ذا را زا سا شا صا ضا طا ظا عا غا کا گا ما نا وا ها یا` individually but for `لا` you can't. The main point of my question is this strange exception.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your issue in `fundamental-mode`, sorry.  In my version of Emacs built for OSX, everything is exactly two (2) individual characters -- including the two characters at issue.  I can select ل and I can select ا   Perhaps try using `(right-char 1)` and `(left-char 1)` -- holding the shift-key while using the arrow left/right is sufficient to select either character on my version of Emacs -- I am in GUI mode, not terminal.

Comment: @lawlist unfortunately for me it does not work as you describe. I use a recent version of Emacs for Windows. I added the corresponding tags.

Comment: I can't answer the question, sadly, but I hope I can point you in the right direction. This behavior seems to be provided by `auto-composition-mode`. You might have a look at the documentation for that function, and the value of the variable `composition-function-table`. If emacs is doing the wrong thing, you might want to pursue the issue on the mailing lists.

Comment: Also, have a look at the lisp file `language/misc-lang.el` (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/language/misc-lang.el). It looks like there is plenty to improve in emacs arabic support.

Comment: @ErikHetzner Thank you for insightful comments.